# Check if my point is in a part of my screen

Tags: python, vb.net, opencv

I know the title is confusing but I don't know how to make it any better. I didn't find anything on google so here I am. So I am using OpenCV and I have a small screen where if my point(Template matches) I would like to give my location(x, y) a name. Check the picture for better understanding, sorry!

[image]

So you get the idea. My script will post a value like x, y every 3 sec and I want to use a function to determine where the point is located. Something to return saying "top side" or "bot side" etc. I don't know where to begin thanks.

It doesn't have to be python if you can provide vb.net example that would work too.

Comment: No idea what you're asking

Comment: @roganjosh Once my openCV template match returns a point (x, y), I would like to use that point to determine the part of the screen the point is located in. Example if the point is in 23, 34 I would like a function to return "top side". Did I make that a little clear?

Comment: Where does the 3 second thing come into it?

Comment: Don't worry about the 3 second, if I had to give you x and y can you check which grid the point is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using opencv python use:

```
import cv2
img=cv2.imread("yourPath")
h,w,_= img.shape()

def func(x,y):
     num_h=h/numOfColumnYouWant
     num_w=w/numOfColumnYouWant
     height_num=(y/num_h)%numOfColumnYouWant
     width_num=(x/num_w)%numOfColumnYouWant
     return height_num,width_num
```

the return value from `func(x,y)` is the row and column, if you want name you can change `numOfColumnYouWant` to 2 and if for example it return 0,0 you know it top left

Comment: My g, you are god! <3

Comment: @shaked litbak `Actually this my first answer`, technically first ***accepted*** answer.